# displaying user posts inside there profile in django

Tags: python, django

I am fairly new to django, i have two models in my app MyProfile and MyPost, users have a profile and they can create a post, it's all work but i want to show posts created by perticular user inside their own profile i tried adding a user_posts object in MyProfile with a filter author but nothing happened.

**MyView**

```
@method_decorator(login_required, name="dispatch")    
class MyProfileDetailView(DetailView):
    model = MyProfile
    def broto(request):
        user = request.user
        user_posts = MyPost.objects.filter(author=request.user).order_by('-cr_date')
        return render(request, {'user_posts':user_posts,'user': user})
```

**Profile page html**

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block content %}
<div class="p-5">
<img src="/media/{{myprofile.pic}}" />
<h1 class="myhead2">{{myprofile.name}}</h1>
<p><strong>Address: {{myprofile.address}}</strong></p>
<p><strong>Phone Number: {{myprofile.phone_no}}</strong></p>
<p><strong>Email: {{myprofile.user.email}}</strong></p>
<p><strong>About:</strong> {{myprofile.purpose}}</p>
<p><strong> Total Donation Recived: {{myprofile.donation_recived}}</strong></p>
<hr>

<table class="table my-3">
    <thead class="thead-dark">
        <tr>
            <th>Title</th>
            <th>Date</th>
            <th>Action</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
{% for MyPost in user_posts %}
        <tr>
            <td>{{MyPost.title}}</td>
            <td>{{MyPost.cr_date | date:"d/m/y"}}</td>
            <td>
            <a class="btn btn-dark btn-sm" href='/covid/mypost/{{n1.id}}'>Read More</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
{% endfor %}
</table>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: I am not particularly knowledgeable about class based views, but I have no idea what you are trying to achieve by calling this method `broto`. Should you not be overriding the `get` method?

Comment: For a `DetailView`, it's even better to override `get_context_data` instead of `get`. See my answer

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in comments, your `broto` methods is probably never executed, that's why nothing happens.

If you use a `DetailView`, the best way to extend a context is to override `get_context_data` method. In your case it could be:

```py
@method_decorator(login_required, name="dispatch")    
class MyProfileDetailView(DetailView):
    model = MyProfile
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        # Call the base implementation first to get a context
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        # Add in a QuerySet of all the user posts
        user_posts = MyPost.objects.filter(author=self.request.user).order_by('-cr_date')
        context['user_posts'] = user_posts
        context['user'] = self.request.user
        return context
```

You can read about it here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/class-based-views/generic-display/#adding-extra-context

Comment: hhey @Michal S. thanks for your answer now it makes complete sense.
I applied your answer but it's giving me an error name 'request' is not defined.

Comment: My mistake, it should be `self.request.user`. I will edit my answer

Comment: S. now it's giving an instance error Cannot query "ahmy": Must be "MyProfile" instance..

Comment: Could you show the line of code that gives that error?